# Is there a standard way to ensure your custom class is Initializable

Tags: java, initialization

I have some POJOs and I have the case in which I receive information about their fields in a non-knowledgeable way. I mean that I receive a Map for each instance, containing some pairs in the pattern [field_name : field_value] and I want to initialize the instance with the information from the map.
So what I did is to create an Initializable interface with single method

`public void initialize (Map initMap) throws Exception`

Then I created a superclass to my POJOs to implement this interface method. That way i ensure that each of the classes I need can be initialized from a Map.

I am not quite sure the pattern I could think of is the correct one, and I feel like there can be a standard Java solution for such trivial problem. So does anyone know if there is a standard way to do the above?

Thanks for the answers!.

EDIT (Answer): After some discussion in the topics below, it was explained to me that what i intend to do is not a standard case and I shall not expect a standard solution for it. I can agree with that. Also as you said its not so much effort to implement it.
What I receive as input to Java can be described as a JSONObject. The information in this JSONObject is to be used to create specific java instances of specific classes that my implementation model consists of. For that reason I am using reflection. The classes that I am instatiating are described with big amount of fields and the information about the instances that i need to create consists of just some of the fields. So my approach is to create the instance, and use Map of that instance field information to initialize the objects with the required information.

Conclusion: My problem is not a standard one. I will implement and manage the Initializable abstraction on my own.

Big thanks to all that gave their opinion!!!

Comment: Does it work? I'd say it is correct then.

Comment: I'd second the answers and comments about "If it works, it's correct" and reflection. But I wanted to add that you may want to explore "object [serialization](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaSerialization/article.html)". I have a feeling that it is what you consider a "standard solution" ...

Answer (score 0):

If the `Map` contains field's name vs. field value, then you can use reflection

```
public void initialize (Map<String, Object> initMap) throws Exception {
        super.initialize(initMap);
        for(Field f : getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            Object value = initMap.get(f.getName());
            f.setAccessible(true);
            f.set(this, value);
        }
}
```

This method you can be placed in any Pojo, and you can make all Pojo extend `IPojo`

```
interface IPojo {
    public void initialize (Map<String, Object> initMap) throws Exception;
}
```

Comment: You should use `getDeclaredFields` to get non-public fields as well. A call to `super.initialize()` should be added as well to set the parent's fields (if any) (or loop the object's superclasses)

Comment: I am using Java reflection. I have almost exactly the same code in my implementation. What i wanted to know is if there is a standard way and to skip manual coding.

Comment: @MilenIgrachev So you want to "persist" an object's state (=its field values) and restore it later ... look for "serialization" and / or "persistance", I would say.

Comment: @Fildor no no, I need the objects for simple calculation later on. I dont need any serialization. After the calculations I leave the objects to the mercy of the garbage collector :). All I need is to initialize them.

Comment: Alright, I see. Just seemed to me that would be interesting to you.

Comment: @MilenIgrachev You usecase is no standard and I doubt there is a standard solution for that. The entity that puts the data into the map could also call direct methods since it obviously knows about the inner structure of your objects. So not using reflection and a Map might be the standard solution you look for. If that entity is on the other hand unable to call methods since it is e.g. a webserver that gives you the data as text it could as well give you something that can be deserialized into objects (see e.g. http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/)

Comment: Thanks for all the comments from everyone!!!. I will add an EDIT: in my post in order to formalize the general answer that I received form you guys. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with "stringly typed" data (where the string in the data must match some name in the source), but you can achieve it using reflection:

```
public void initialize(Map<String, Object> initMap) throws Exception {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : initMap.entrySet())
        getClass().getDeclaredField(entry.getKey()).set(this, entry.getValue());
}
```

Note: It is not necessary to call `setAccessible(true)` when calling `set()` from within the owning class; private fields are always accessible to the class itself.

Comment: I am using Java reflection. I have almost exactly the same code in my implementation. What i wanted to know is if there is a standard way and to skip manual coding.

Comment: @MilenIgrachev I'm not aware of any library other shortcut, but this isn't much code either.